# change checkbox label after select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some checkboxes (101) which labels should change based on a select input. The JS I have only runs for one, which is logical. Though I'm not very familiar with jquery functions, I don't know how to proceed for all the 101 checkboxes.

the inputs :

```
<?php

    for ($i = 1; $i < 102; $i++): //adjust this number to whatever number of checkboxes you want
        echo '<div class="each_checkboxes">';
        //  $j = sprintf('%04u', $i);

        echo '<label id="contact" for="checkbox"></label>';
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tape[]" id="checkbox" value=""/>';

        echo '</div>';

    endfor;
?>
```

the select :

```
<select id="method" name="server" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white" required>
    <option value="0" default>Choose server</option>
    <option value="server1">server 1</option>
    <option value="server2">server 2</option>
</select>
```

the js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#method').change(function () {
        var method = $('option:selected').val();

        if (method == "server1") {

            $('#contact').text("MA" + i);

        } else if (method == "server2") {

              $('#contact').text("SAS" + i);

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `class` instead of `id`, because `id` should be unique for each element. Try like following.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i < 102; $i++): 

        echo '<div class="each_checkboxes">';

        echo '<label class="contact" for="checkbox'.$i.'"></label>';
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tape[]" id="checkbox'.$i.'" value=""/>';

        echo '</div>';

    endfor;
?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#method').change(function () {
        var method = $('option:selected').val(),
            text = "";

        if (method == "server1") {
            text = "MA";
        } else if (method == "server2") {
            text = "SAS";
        }

        $('.contact').each(function (i) {
            var value = text + (++i);
            $(this).text(value);
            $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).val(value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You question is not clear. There may any other problem in your original code. See this [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). @Xibition

Comment: this is the only code I have. question : does it recognize the same var "i" in jquery ?

Comment: No. But you can use `each()` method. See the updated answer. Hope it will solve your problem. @Xibition

Comment: sorry to bother you again ... but can I ask you one more question please, how do I pass this same value (MA23 for eg) to the checkboxes value, so that I can use it in the DB ... (store MA23 in db)

Comment: okey so I added this  
`  $('.contact').each(function(i) {
             $(this).text(text + (++i));
          var q = $(this).text();
           $( "[type=checkbox]" ).val(q);
        });`

But it always gives me the last one (MA101)

Comment: `[type=checkbox]` selects all checkbox. Do exactly what I did.@Xibition

Comment: well I tried this but .... it doesnt get the MA/SAS only the numbers.. $('.contact').each(function(i) {
             $(this).text(text + (++i));
             var q = $(this).text();
        });
        $( ".check" ).each(function(q){
          $(this).val(q+1);
        });

Comment: Why you tried like this? Why not like mine? @Xibition

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by 'mine'... i used .each *hides in a bush* xD

Comment: oh ... don't mind me this afternoon ... i didn't pay attention .. omg. Well the output is correct but now MA/SAS is not displayed, only the numbers ... sorry again .. really ..

Comment: NEVERMIND got it (y) so sorry again for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to `id` attribute in your jQuery selector which will only look for first match in your dom You need to assign a class to your label and reference to that when changing you label text then this will work.

```
<?php

  for ($i = 1; $i < 102; $i++): //adjust this number to whatever number of checkboxes you want
      echo '<div class="each_checkboxes">';
    //  $j = sprintf('%04u', $i);

      echo '<label id="contact" class="contact" for="checkbox"></label>';
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tape[]" id="checkbox" value=""/>';

      echo '</div>';

endfor;
  ?>
```

and in jQuery just use class selector like this;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#method').change(
    function () {
        var method = $('option:selected').val();

        if (method == "server1") {

            $('.contact').text("MA" + i);

        } else if (method == "server2") {

              $('.contact').text("SAS" + i);

        }
    });

});
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use label class instead of id

```
<?php

  for ($i = 1; $i < 102; $i++): //adjust this number to whatever number of checkboxes you want
      echo '<div class="each_checkboxes">';
    //  $j = sprintf('%04u', $i);

      echo '<label class="contact" for="checkbox"></label>';
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tape[]" id="checkbox" value=""/>';

      echo '</div>';

endfor;
  ?>
```

js code is

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#method').change(
    function () {
        var method = $('option:selected',this).val();

        if (method == "server1") {

            $('.each_checkboxes label.contact').html("MA" + i);

        } else if (method == "server2") {

              $('.each_checkboxes label.contact').html("SAS" + i);

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "class" for your checkbox's label instead of "id". Basically, "id" of an element should be unique. But class, more than one elements can have the same class.

So, the label should be like this:

```
<label class="contact" for="checkbox"></label>
```

Then your onchange method should be like this:

```
$('#method').change(
  function () {
      var method = $('option:selected').val();
      if (method == "server1") {
        $('.contact').text("MA" + i);
      } else if (method == "server2") {
        $('.contact').text("SAS" + i);
      }
});
```